# Firebase doesn't keep up with user deletions but only sometimes?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a strange scenario that I could use some help with.

In the app, the user has a list of tasks to do that are listed in a typical `tableView`. When the user taps on a cell, the table updates with a checkmark and the data is sent to Firebase. That all works well.

The problem is when the user swipes from right and removes the item's checkmark (thus resetting the cell back to 'blank'). The checkmark disappears, the local array updates, and Firebase should delete the value. If the user just does this for one cell, it works fine. But if the user resets multiple cells one right after the other, Firebase fails to "keep up", and only some of the data is removed from Firebase.

However, if the user goes slowly and removes each item with a, say, 3 second pause between swipes, Firebase keeps up and deletes the items appropriately.

How can this be? I've read the Firebase documentation, and I can't find where it says you have to slowly remove items or else it won't work. I must be missing something.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
for (pointsIndex, pointsItem) in Points.pointsArray.enumerated() {
            // isolate item in Points array (current user, current category, current item name, and current date)
            if pointsItem.user == self.currentUserName &&
                pointsItem.itemCategory == category &&
                pointsItem.itemName == isoArrayForItem.first?.itemName &&
                Calendar.current.isDate(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: pointsItem.itemDate), inSameDayAs: selectedDate) {

                // remove item from points array
                Points.pointsArray.remove(at: pointsIndex)

                // update Firebase points
                // NOTE: since user can only tap on one item at a time when creating the item, there technically should be only one item for that user at that precise moment for us to delete
                // That's why we query the itemDate
                ref.child("points").child(self.currentUserName).queryOrdered(byChild: "itemDate").queryEqual(toValue: pointsItem.itemDate).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                    snapshot.ref.removeValue()
                })

                // update user's income array & income label
                if let index = Income.currentIncomeArray.index(where: { $0.user == currentUserName }) {
                    Income.currentIncomeArray[index].currentPoints -= pointsItem.valuePerTap
                    Income.progressMeter -= CGFloat(pointsItem.valuePerTap)
                    if category == "daily habits" { habitProgressMeter -= CGFloat(pointsItem.valuePerTap) }
                    updateUserIncomeOnFirebase(user: currentUserName, index: index)
                    incomeLabel.text = Points.formatMoney(value: Double(Income.currentIncomeArray[index].currentPoints) / 100, showCents: true, roundIfMoreThan10: false, showDollarSign: true)
                    updateProgressMeters(animated: true, duration: 0.25)
                }

                updateWeeklyJobsArray()
                tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }
        }
```

And the `updateUserIncomeOnFirebase` method always fires. But here it is in case it has some relevance to the solution:

```
func updateUserIncomeOnFirebase(user: String, index: Int) {
    ref.child("mpIncome").updateChildValues([user : Income.currentIncomeArray[index].currentPoints])
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the Firebase query isn't finished before the other code runs and somehow that's causing the problem? I wouldn't think so, because Firebase is asynchronous, but maybe I'm incorrect in my understanding?

Comment: On a side note, I've noticed that Firebase doesn't like multiple calls within a `for` loop. If there's just one call in a `for` loop, all the items in that loop get executed. But if there's a second call in the same loop, sometimes those won't get called. Could that be related as well?